# Canvas background color not as white as I need

Tags: wpf, colors, background, wpf-controls

I am setting the background color of my Canvas as 'white'. However when I compare my canvas with a vendor application, their canvas is 'whiter', which is the color I want for my canvas too. I have looked at all the color choices available for canvas background color but nothing makes my canvas any whiter than it is. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: may be your eyes determine which is whiter, for example, someone may feel a white with a **little** light pink or light lime look whiter to their eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

Use one of the browser plugins to get the actual "white" color of their app.

One example of a color-picker is Chrome plus the ColorZilla extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorzilla/bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp